# Parsing int from string produces incorrect result

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I'm trying to use `parseInt()` to get an `int` from a `String` and I read about `radix` so I'm passing `10` as the second parameter:

```
String str= "02";
int test= Integer.parseInt(str, 10);

System.out.println("Should be 2:" + test);
```

The output is actually `0`. What's gone wrong here?

Comment: The code works for me. The result is 2.

Comment: code is fine, I'm sure u are running a different class (it happens to me all the time :) ).

Comment: your code is fine,check the result [here](https://ideone.com/CdhKhO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int test= Integer.parseInt(str, 10);
```

Is working nice for me...

```
String str = "02";
int test= Integer.parseInt(str, 10);
System.out.println(">"+test);
```

Output:

> 2

If you don't put radix can be interpreted as [`octal`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)... but in my computer output is correct. Double check if you are not executing in background another conversion...

Comment: The documentation says: `parseInt(String s, int radix)` - it should work with `parseInt(str,10);`?